# How to dynamically add rows to column in power bi/power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm facing a challenge in power bi where I need to join Table 1 & Table 2 but the catch is Table 2 needs to be pivoted before joining.

Input:
Table 1
[image]

Table 2
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

How to build the output table when the Table 2 rows will be increasing daily

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result needs a combination of Unpivot, Merge and Pivot steps.

You can follow the following steps:

1. Convert the `Date` column to Text type.
2. Unpivot columns `Sales in KG` & `Sales in Amount` from `Table 2` - it will create 2 columns called `Attribute` & `Value`
3. Merge columns `Date` & `Attribute` to create a new column (*lets call it `columnHeaders`*) - this will be in the format - `1/3/22 Sales in KG`, `1/3/22 Sales in Amount` ...
4. Merge `Table 1` into `Table 2` and expand the `Product Name` column

   - Now you will have 4 columns - `Product Code`, `columnHeaders`, `Value`, & `Product Name`
5. Pivot `columnHeader` using the `Value` column for values

You should have your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you try to unpivot your table. Just use a Matrix visualization:

Model relationship:
[image]
Imput data + output:
[image]
[image]

```
sum of kg = CALCULATE(sum(Table2[Sales in kg]))
```

Comment: I’m trying to un pivot because I need add furthermore calculation - weekly return, weekly growth & group products and then show it in visualisation